# Shopify add cart properties. How do this properties work? It disappears after page refresh

Tags: shopify, cart

I am setting properties when adding to cart.
Ex:

```
var formdata=[
  "items":{
     id:123456,
     quantity:1
     properties:{'flag':true}
   }
];
added using api : /cart/add.js
```

Details I get from cart.js without refresh

```
response from : /cart/add.js and cart.js
[
    {
        "id": 32423423423423,
        "properties": {
            "flag": true
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "variant_id": 42705234345345,
    }
]
```

The above items get added successfully to cart. After adding I again fetch the cart details and It has this properties value.But when I refresh the page cart items properties does not have any value.

Ex Currently I am getting this only when page is refreshed:

```
response from cart.js after page refresh
properties:{
   Ref: 0
}
```

What this properties is?

Why is this happening? If worked, will this properties be available on order create webhook? It only disappears when refreshed. Moreover main reason to add this properties is to receive this properties in order-create webhook to distinguish from normal order. If anyone having other alternative please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a product to the cart like so:

```
fetch('/cart/add.js', {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    items: [
      {
        quantity: 1,
        id: 33116507373620,
        properties: {
          'flag': true
        }
      }
    ]
  })
})
```

And getting the cart.js like so:

```
fetch('/cart/add.js').then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Will get you result like so:

```
{
  ...
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 33116507373620,
      "properties": {
        "flag": true
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

From there on what you are doing to not get this result I'm not sure, since this is working/tested and there is no issue.

Please double check if you are targeting the correct object once you get the `cart.js` response. (there is no properties direct object, it's under `items[0].properties` in this case)

Comment: The response after adding to cart does have properties and flag value and also cart.js response have properties and flag value. But the properties value loses when I reload the page. It has value as shown in the question. @drip

Comment: No doubt cart gets added with properties value. The only problem is it shows Ref : 0 when page is reloaded. Moreover I want this properties flag on order create webhook. So that I can distinguish between order @drip.

Comment: @RahulBaraiya I don't know where this Ref: 0 is coming from. I'm just saying how it works normally, if it doesn't work for you this way it means that you have additional code that overwrite the default functionality (like overwriting your cart items). I can't help you here since I don't know the full extend of your code and I'm not sure what goes behind the scene, I'm just layout out the facts.

Comment: Realy sorry. My mistake, there is a code that is over writing it. @drip Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to represent the properties parameter in a name/value structure as follows:

```
var formdata=[
  items: {
     id: 123456,
     quantity: 1,
     properties: [
       {
         name: "flag",
         value: "true"
       }
     ]
   }
];
```